# Simple tikz `\draw` -| fails when the points are exchanged, why is that?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

Here is the MWE :

```
    \documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \usepackage{pgfplots} %pour Tikz et pgfplot
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning} % pour le positionnement relatif

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
        \node (start) at (0,0) {} ;
        \coordinate (top) at (1,1) ;
        \coordinate (bottom) at (1,-1) ;
        \coordinate (join) at (3,0) ;
        \draw (top -| join) -- (join);
        %\draw (join) -- ( top -| join ); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

You can check that if you uncomment the last `\draw` compilation fails. You'll get :

```
Package pgf Error: No shape named join is known.
```

And my question is why ? When the line above is the same with the point exchanged

Answer : remove the space `join` like so :

```
    \draw (join) -- ( top -| join);
```

and it works...

Comment: The error is not `shape named join is known`, but `shape named join ​ is known`. Note the extra space after `join`. Apparently Ti*k*Z trims the leading but not the trailing space... If you use `\draw (join) -- (top-|join);` it works.

Comment: Ok, that was silly, you can answer if you want the validation

Comment: I marked a duplicate. It's a fairly common problem. Although I think Ti*k*Z should trim spaces...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer : remove the space after `join` like so :

```
\draw (join) -- ( top -| join);
```

and it works

Comment: How do I set the subject as answered ?

Comment: Since you self-answered I think the site makes you wait one or two days before marking your answer as correct. After that you just click the checkmark to the right of your answer. See here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852/134574

Comment: And thank you by the way

Comment: You're welcome :-) I opened a new issue in the PGF repo (https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/747). Let's see if this changes :-)